# Best way to make place cards in LaTeX

Tags: cards

What's the best way to make a lot of foldable place cards like the following in LaTeX:

I want to be able to specify the size of the card. They should be printed in a space saving way, such that I can cut them out easily after printing.

[image: Place Card]

[image: Place Card 2]

Comment: Use the `geometry` package to set the size and margins. Plenty of examples on this site.

Comment: A design suggestion: Drop the words "Table No:". If you see all the place cards on the tables and there's a number on each one of them, it's perfectly clear that that's gonna be the table number. Imho it'll look much better and distract from the name less. Oh, and seeing that you're actually a regular here, you might wanna think about a more unique user name, unless you're purposely going for this absolute anonymity of course.

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the suggestion. The pictures are just examples I picked from the web to make clear what I mean.

Answer (score 11):

If you have a large number of cards to organise and produce, the [labels package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/labels) may be useful for this. In particular, it will allow you to:

1. Lay out the cards as labels, appropriately sized and placed for
   printing and cutting;
2. Create a command to format a single card; and
3. Process a list of names to produce all the cards

Comment: Mind including a small example?

Comment: @N.N.: I'm afraid I don't have a concrete example, sorry. (In mitigation, I *did* say "may be useful" -- it just struck me as a good fit, especially for fitting [multiple things of the same shape and layout] on to a page.)