# Template (?) for Table Name Cards for a Formal Dinner

Tags: templates, cards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to make place cards in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36723/best-way-to-make-place-cards-in-latex)

So I have an event coming up and I would like to generate a bunch of Name cards to assign where people are seating. It would have the guest's name, and entree they RSVP with.

Any ideas?

Comment: What about http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36723/best-way-to-make-place-cards-in-latex