# Passport photographs using resize

Tags: graphics, scaling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength{\oH}
\newlength{\oW}
\newlength{\rH}
\newlength{\cH}
\newcommand\PrintImage[3]{% width, height, image
  \settototalheight{\oH}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \settowidth{\oW}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \setlength{\rH}{\oH * \ratio{#1}{\oW}}
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\rH < #2}}{
    \includegraphics[width=#1]{#3}%
  }{%
    \setlength{\cH}{(\rH-#2)*\ratio{\oW}{#1}}%
    \includegraphics[width=#1,clip,trim=0 \cH{} 0 0]{#3}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage}
\end{document}
```

Using this code you can create 2x2 inch passport photograph. If one is using a4 paper, how can we arrange the photograph in columns so that multiple passport photographs can be generated on one page and photopaper is not wasted. Just for curiosity and fun.

Comment: This sounds like a fit for the `labels` package. Take a look at [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36731/344)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a tabular `environment`, the precise order depends on the size of the photograph paper?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,tmargin=0.2cm,bmargin=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength{\oH}
\newlength{\oW}
\newlength{\rH}
\newlength{\cH}
\newcommand\PrintImage[3]{% width, height, image
  \settototalheight{\oH}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \settowidth{\oW}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \setlength{\rH}{\oH * \ratio{#1}{\oW}}
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\rH < #2}}{
    \includegraphics[width=#1]{#3}%
  }{%
    \setlength{\cH}{(\rH-#2)*\ratio{\oW}{#1}}%
    \includegraphics[width=#1,clip,trim=0 \cH{} 0 0]{#3}%
  }%
}

\newlength{\extraspaceforcutting}
\setlength{\extraspaceforcutting}{0.2ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{@{}c@{}}}
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting] 
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]
\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} &\PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} & \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version with a loop

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=0.5cm,rmargin=0.5cm,tmargin=0.2cm,bmargin=0.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{forloop}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength{\oH}
\newlength{\oW}
\newlength{\rH}
\newlength{\cH}
\newcommand\PrintImage[3]{% width, height, image
  \settototalheight{\oH}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \settowidth{\oW}{\includegraphics{#3}}%
  \setlength{\rH}{\oH * \ratio{#1}{\oW}}
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\rH < #2}}{
    \includegraphics[width=#1]{#3}%
  }{%
    \setlength{\cH}{(\rH-#2)*\ratio{\oW}{#1}}%
    \includegraphics[width=#1,clip,trim=0 \cH{} 0 0]{#3}%
  }%
}%

\newcounter{rowcounter}
\newcounter{columncounter}

\newcounter{maxcolumns}
\newcounter{maxrows}
\setcounter{maxcolumns}{3}
\setcounter{maxrows}{9}%
\newlength{\extraspaceforcutting}
\setlength{\extraspaceforcutting}{0.2ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{\value{maxcolumns}}{@{}c@{}}}
  \forloop{rowcounter}{1}{\value{rowcounter} < \numexpr\value{maxrows}}{%
    \forloop{columncounter}{1}{\value{columncounter} < \numexpr\value{maxcolumns}+1}{%
      \PrintImage{6cm}{2cm}{yourimage} \ifnumless{\value{columncounter}}{3}{&}{}%
    }%
    \ifnumless{\value{rowcounter}}{\value{maxrows}-1}{\tabularnewline[\extraspaceforcutting]%
    }{} % no newline 
  }%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't we have something like loop

Comment: @Vaibhav: Yes, but that means that you either have to compute the names of the images or use the same image all the time?

Comment: Normally person require multiple copies of same photograph , so loop should be ideal . If image is 2x2 inches, how can we adjust it on a4 paper?

Comment: @Vaibhav:See the update please